# Activeadmin | How this flash message was generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

On creation of new Admin I get message "*Admin was successfully created.*"

But I need to override that. For that I did: ***/app/admin/admin.rb***

```
controller do
  def create
    super do
      redirect_to admin_admins_path, notice: 'My custom message' and return
    end
  end
end
```

This served the purpose for now, but out of curosity, I want to know **how the message is generated?**

I searched all YMLs as suggested in this [issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3171) and also all inside activeadmin gem, but in vain!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking for is not exactly in the `activeadmin` gem. The `BaseController` from `activeadmin` inherits from the `InheritedResources::Base` of the `inherited_resources` gem, which in turn uses `respond_with` (former) Rails function which is now in the `responders` gem.
So if you want to look exactly how that flash message gets set you'll have to follow that gem trail.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Following is the same I think: https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Comment: Indeed, that's the gem.